# Is it discussed how saidin and saidar work together?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, magical-theory

In the series *Wheel of Time*, is it discussed how the sides of the True Source, *saidin* and *saidar*, work together?

On a similar note: what happens when they do? Would the male taint of *saidin* have any bearing on such a weave? If so, what type of effect?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'how they work together'? I could quote descriptions of how the channelling characters perceive the weaves when both *saidin* and *saidar* are being used together on the same task, but not sure if that's what you're looking for?

Comment: @Randal'Thor No, what I mean is if 2 or more people: at least one male, and one female combine their weaves in order to make a larger weave, how does that work? (I know it CAN work, because it's mentioned that it was done in the past). But now that the male half of the True Source was tainted, does it happen throughout the series? And if so, how does the taint affect things?

Comment: @JesseCohoon  How far into the series have you read?  To make sure I'm understanding you:  You're asking if combined weaving occurs in the series and what happens when it does occur?

Comment: @kuhl about 3/4ths (then it started getting tiresome to reread the books from the beginning every time a new book came out) I know (from reading summaries) that the male part of the True Source is cleansed at some point, but I'm wanting to know if BEFORE that point does combined weaving occur. If it does, does the taint have any effect on things

Comment: Probably the ward around Callandor is the best example. I'll see if I can dig up some quotes. The taint doesn't seem to affect combined weaves, as it was set after the Breaking iirc. It did affect the Ways though...

Comment: Waiting for Perrin to show up. :)

Comment: It is mentioned once or twice that the greatest of the works of power were done using both Saidin and Saidar. However, since the breaking and the tainting of Saidin none of those who weild Saidar are willing to link with the male channelers... till the later books at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is:  When a man and a woman link, how do weaves happen, then the answer is two-fold:

The person who is guiding the flows either uses their power (saidin/saidar), and the opposite power naturally reinforces their weave, or, they can channel saidin and saidar simultaneously and independently [if they know how].

During the

> cleansing of saidin

Rand channeled both Saidin and Saidar to achieve his purpose.  However, with Perrin, Neald explained that saidar merely reinforced his channeling of saidin.  In another instance, Semirhage had to remember how a certain effect was created by Saidin when using the domination band, which indicates that she had directly channelled Saidin herself [the domination band didn't exist in the AoL]

This can be explained by the fact that knowing how to work one of the powers doesn't provide the same expertise in the other, as all of the weaves, mechanisms, and even basic channeling are different.  But as a woman, for example, if you are linked to a man, you can channel Saidin directly if you have learned how to do it.  However, the reinforcement method requires no knowledge of the other power.  Androl became much stronger in the power when linked to Pevara, even though the amount of Saidin he could channel was a trickle.

Comment: One piece of information is needed in order to have me accept this as an answer: what is a domination band? (or if there's a term for it, please put it in there and keep the word domination as a definition)

Comment: @JesseCohoon The Domination Band is the black a'dam for male channelers.

Answer (score 4):

They weren't exactly used together. Supposedly the best link is 2 women,  1 man with one of the women controlling the flows, but both saidar and saidin have limitations, that disappear when a man and woman link. in one of the earlier books it mentions that linked, a man and woman are 10x strong, not 2x.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide some links and/or quotes to support your argument.

Comment: Book 3, the battle between Nyneave and Moghedien...As they basically try to shield/still one another, Moghedien talks to Nyneave to try to distract her

Comment: Not in the comments; and preferably, provide actual quotes, so people don't have to search the book just for a few sentences.

Comment: Sorry...have read all WoT books at multiple times but am new to this site...will be more researched in future...thanks

Comment: You're welcome, keep up posting good answers!